# Packet Data Sniffing from ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets, packet-capture, packet-sniffers

I would like to sniff packet data using C#
I need it to sniff all types of data not only HTTP

When I try to do it I get this error:

System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress) at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)

```
public void StartCapture(string InterfaceIp)
{
        try
        {
                //Start capturing the packets...
                //For sniffing the socket to capture the packets has to be a raw socket, with the
                //address family being of type internetwork, and protocol being IP
                mainSocket = new System.Net.Sockets.Socket(System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                    System.Net.Sockets.SocketType.Raw, System.Net.Sockets.ProtocolType.IP);
                //Bind the socket to the selected IP address
                mainSocket.Bind(new System.Net.IPEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(InterfaceIp), 0));
                //Set the socket  options
                mainSocket.SetSocketOption(System.Net.Sockets.SocketOptionLevel.IP,            //Applies only to IP packets
                                           System.Net.Sockets.SocketOptionName.HeaderIncluded, //Set the include the header
                                           true);                           //option to true
                byte[] byTrue = new byte[4] { 1, 0, 0, 0 };
                byte[] byOut = new byte[4] { 1, 0, 0, 0 }; //Capture outgoing packets
                //Socket.IOControl is analogous to the WSAIoctl method of Winsock 2
                mainSocket.IOControl(System.Net.Sockets.IOControlCode.ReceiveAll,              //Equivalent to SIO_RCVALL constant
                    //of Winsock 2
                                     byTrue,
                                     byOut);

                //Start receiving the packets asynchronously
                mainSocket.BeginReceive(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags.None,
                    new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Report Exception
        }
}
```

Note:I am using ASP.Net & it is really important to sniff the data and not only the headers of the packet

I think the problem is related to not having the right privileges to access to socket, although using impersonation didn't solve the problem

I found the solution to my problem, it's related to a recent implementation that limits binding to a socket that is protected and limited to a single ip address

Here are some interesting links

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc150667(v=vs.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740668%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Suggestion: remove the try/catch block, turn on [ASP.NET Health Monitoring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398933.aspx), and ASP.NET will "report" all of the details of the exception.

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK with using a library, [SharpPcap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharppcap/) is a nice one and it's very simple to use.

Comment: I cannot use external libraries

Comment: He's not asking your opinion about what library etc. to use. He is asking about how to fix an error with Raw sockets. I have used raw sockets and sniff all my packets very simply without any need for installing SharpPCap etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm experimenting with raw sockets.

I fixed this error,

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 'An attempt was made to access a
>   socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions'

simply by running visual studio in administrator mode.